# Simulate display: inline in React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

React Native doesn't support the CSS `display` property, and by default all elements use the behavior of `display: flex` (no `inline-flex` either). Most non-flex layouts can be simulated with flex properties, but I'm flustered with inline text.

My app has a container that contains several words in text, some of which need formatting. This means I need to use spans to accomplish the formatting. In order to achieve wrapping of the spans, I can set the container to use `flex-wrap: wrap`, but this will only allow wrapping at the end of a span rather than the traditional inline behavior of wrapping at word breaks.

The problem visualized (spans in yellow):

[image]

(via http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoWmdm?editors=110)

Is there a way to get proper wrapping and true inline simulation using flex properties?

Comment: There's a solution for this in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335695/3051080

Comment: could you please tell ,did this worked as shown in image?  I am trying to put image in between two texts, with same effect as shown by you in image.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can get this effect by wrapping text elements in other text elements the way you would wrap a span in a div or another element:

```
<View>
  <Text><Text>This writing should fill most of the container </Text><Text>This writing should fill most of the container</Text></Text>       
</View>
```

You can also get this effect by declaring a flexDirection:'row' property on the parent along with a flexWrap: 'wrap'. The children will then display inline:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
  <Text>one</Text><Text>two</Text><Text>Three</Text><Text>Four</Text><Text>Five</Text>
</View>
```

Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/-rzWGg) example.

https://rnplay.org/apps/-rzWGg

Comment: Note that adding `flexWrap: 'wrap'` causes the whole text node to flow onto the next line if it would wrap, it won't cause part of the text to remain on the initial line while the rest of the sentence flows to the next one.

Comment: Neither `padding` nor `margin` work for inner `Text`s

Comment: one problem, this doesn't allow changing the fontFamily :/

Comment: This will not give the desired effect unless you break each word up into a separate text element.

Answer (score 15):

You can only nest text nodes without using flex to get the desired effect.
Like this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

```
<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
  I am bold
  <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
    and red
  </Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 11):

I haven't found a proper way to inline text blocks with other content. Our current "hackish" workaround is to split every single word in a text string into its own  block so flexWrap wraps properly for each word.

Comment: This works and just shows how much is still missing from React Native. Sad, just sad.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, simple and clean.

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'CUSTOM_FONT', ... }}>
   <Text>Lorem ipsum</Text>
   <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>&nbsp;dolor sit amet.</Text>
</Text>
```

Result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the following use case:

I needed a text that can wrap with different sizes, and throughout that text, I wanted to underscore some of the words (to indicate that they are clickable).

It's quite simple expect for the case that you can't control the underline in any way (how close is it, what color is it, so on) - this led me through the rabbit hole, and eventually coming up with the solution of splitting every word, and wrapping it in separate Text component, wrapped with View.

I'll paste the code here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../../styles/Colors';
import Fonts from '../../styles/Fonts';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default class SaltText extends React.Component {

  getTheme (type) {

    if (type === 'robomonoregular10gray') {
      return {
          fontSize: Fonts.SIZES.TEN,
          fontFamily: Fonts.ROBOTOMONO_REGULAR,
          color: Colors.getColorOpacity(Colors.GRAY, 70),
          lineHeight: Fonts.SIZES.TEN + 10
      };
    }

    throw new Error('not supported');
  }

  splitText (text) {
    const parts = [];
    const maps = [];

    let currentPart = '';
    let matchIndex = 0;

    for (const letter of text) {

      const isOpening = letter === '[';
      const isClosing = letter === ']';

      if (!isOpening && !isClosing) {
        currentPart += letter;
        continue;
      }

      if (isOpening) {
        parts.push(currentPart);
        currentPart = '';
      }

      if (isClosing) {
        parts.push(`[${matchIndex}]`);
        maps.push(currentPart);
        currentPart = '';
        matchIndex++;
      }
    }

    const partsModified = [];
    for (const part of parts) {
      const splitted = part
        .split(' ')
        .filter(f => f.length);

      partsModified.push(...splitted);
    }

    return { parts: partsModified, maps };
  }

  render () {

    const textProps = this.getTheme(this.props.type);
    const children = this.props.children;

    const getTextStyle = () => {
      return {
        ...textProps,
      };
    };

    const getTextUnderlineStyle = () => {
      return {
        ...textProps,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: textProps.color
      };
    };

    const getViewStyle = () => {
      return {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
      };
    };

    const { parts, maps } = this.splitText(children);

    return (
      <View style={getViewStyle()}>
        {parts.map((part, index) => {

          const key = `${part}_${index}`;
          const isLast = parts.length === index + 1;

          if (part[0] === '[') {
            const mapIndex = part.substring(1, part.length - 1);
            const val = maps[mapIndex];
            const onPressHandler = () => {
              this.props.onPress(parseInt(mapIndex, 10));
            };
            return (
              <View key={key} style={getTextUnderlineStyle()}>
                <Text style={getTextStyle()} onPress={() => onPressHandler()}>
                  {val}{isLast ? '' : ' '}
                </Text>
              </View>
            );
          }

          return (
            <Text key={key} style={getTextStyle()}>
              {part}{isLast ? '' : ' '}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
  renderPrivacy () {

    const openTermsOfService = () => {
      Linking.openURL('https://reactnativecode.com');
    };

    const openPrivacyPolicy = () => {
      Linking.openURL('https://reactnativecode.com');
    };

    const onUrlClick = (index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        openTermsOfService();
      }

      if (index === 1) {
        openPrivacyPolicy();
      }
    };

    return (
      <SaltText type="robomonoregular10gray" onPress={(index) => onUrlClick(index)}>
        By tapping Create an account or Continue, I agree to SALT\'s [Terms of Service] and [Privacy Policy]
      </SaltText>
    );
  }
```

this is the end result:

[image: example]

Comment: Sadly, this seems like the only "reasonable" solution. Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a lot of texts (like is my case). Maybe it could be done in this way. It's ugly but it works.

```
  const words =  text.split(' ');
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {words.map((word) => (
        <Text key={word} className="pr-1">
          {word}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

I'm using [nativewind](https://www.nativewind.dev/) for styling.

Comment: While I get what you're trying to do here, I pretty strongly recommend against this approach. Wrapping is still something that controlled by the parent (which you haven't described), you potentially create unneeded padding on the right edge of the parent container, you ruin all RTL language support, and you could very easily cause a performance issue with all the additional layout.