# React-native view auto width by text inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As far as I know, react-native stylesheet doesn't supports min-width/max-width property.

I have a view and text inside. The view in auto width doesn't resize by inherit text element.

How to fix that issue and make view width automatically set using text width?

My code is:

```
 <View style={{backgroundColor: '#000000'}}>
      <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>Sample text here</Text>
 </View>
```

In common HTML/CSS I would realize so:

```
 <div style="background-color: #000; display: inline;">Sample text here</div>
```

Notice:  flex: 1 on parent view is not helpful for me.
Text appears as

```
"Sam"
"ple"
"Tex"
"t"
```

Answer (score 482):

"alignSelf" does the same as 'display: inline-block' would in common HTML/CSS and it works very well for me.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: '#000000', alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>
 <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>
  Sample text here
 </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Genius, thanks. Is the second `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` on the `Text` itself necessary?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I confirm -- `alignSelf: 'flex-start'` isn't required on `Text`.

Comment: @SanketSahu Thanks for updating the answer. I re-read my comment and was like "what second `alignSelf`?"

Comment: Absolutely yes! I suggest to use 'minHeight' property also!

Comment: Was wondering why the view was taking up the full width.. this fixed it!

Comment: it was taking the whole width because the `View` was a flex and by default it will have `alignItems` as `stretch`. we need to override this `alignItems` to something that is not `stretch` e.g `center` if you want your text centered

Comment: 'center' or 'flex-end' works fine as well (for center and right align)

Comment: In the parent View, it worked for me when I used only `flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'` (react native 0.72.5)

Comment: Cursed ,but okay working thanks

Answer (score 84):

## Two Solutions

#### Text component fits the text content

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#containers

You can wrap `<Text>` components into another `<Text>` component.

By doing this *everything inside is no longer using the flexbox layout but using text layout*.

```html
<Text>
   <Text>{'Your text here'}</Text>
</Text>
```

[image: Render 1]

#### View container adapt to nested Text component's content

In that case you need to use the props `alignSelf` in order to see the container shrink to the size of its content.

```html
<View>
  <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', padding: 12}} >
     <Text>{'Your text here'}</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

[image: Render 2]

Comment: After hours of struggling with flexbox, this simple trick solved EVERYTHING for me.

Comment: The second option works very good, but only applying style={{ flex:0 }} to the view where has the text, can work! (it does apply to any other child within the view, like if you have a button, or an icon, or another view, when you make flex:0, you remove the property that components to grow using flexbox)

Comment: `alignSelf: 'center'` also works if you just pass it to the text component. Good answer otherwise.

Answer (score 38):

**tldr: set `alignItems` to any value other than `'stretch'` for the style of the parent View of your View containing Text**

The issue your facing is likely related to React Native's default value for `alignItems: 'stretch'` on a `<View />` element. Basically, all `<View />` elements by default cause their children to stretch along the cross axis (axis opposite to the `flexDirection`). Setting `alignItems` to any value other than `"stretch"` ("baseline", "flex-start", "flex-end", or "center") on the parent View prevents this behavior and addresses your problem.

Below is an example where there are two View elements contained inside of a parent View with a blue border. The two View elements each contain a View wrapped around a Text element. In the case of the first View with default styling, the yellow child View expands horizontally to fill the entire width. In the second View where `alignItems: 'baseline'`, the pink View does not expand and stays the size of it's child Text element.

[image]

```
<View style={{ borderWidth: 5, borderColor: 'blue' }}>
    <View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
    <View style={{ alignItems: 'baseline' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

The `align-items` property is explained well [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/).

Answer (score 29):

This work for me.

```
<View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    <Text>abc</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 27):

If you want to apply width to `View` based on `<Text>` , you can do something like this :

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <Text>
     {text}
   </Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignSelf:"flex-start",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@vivekdoshi2/auto-width)**

Answer (score 13):

Or simply:

```
  <Text style={{color: '#ffffff', alignSelf: 'center'}}>Sample text here</Text>
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this way for your requirement:

Here my height is Constant and i am enlarging the width by the length of text.

```
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{
        height: 30, width: 'auto', justifyContent:'center', 
        alignItems: 'center'}}>

        <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Now View will enlarge byitself</Text>

    </View>
  </View>
```

For Both Height and Width Try Changing the height inside the View style to 'auto' full code bellow:

```
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{
        height: 'auto', width: 'auto', justifyContent:'center', 
        alignItems: 'center'}}>

        <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Now View will enlarge byitself</Text>

    </View>
  </View>
```

Also try Giving padding to the View for arrange the text properly.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `alignSelf` to the text style, it won't take the whole width

```
 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>{'Your text here'}</Text>       
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'baseline'}}>{'Your text here'}</Text>       
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>{'Your text here'}</Text>
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>{'Your text here'}</Text>
 </View>
```

These worked for me

Answer (score 5):

It works with Nicholas answer unless you want to center the view somewhere. In that case, you could add a wrapper view around the view to obtain the width of its content and set `alignItems: 'center'`. Like this:

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            <Text>{'Your text is here'}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
```

The background color is added to show the size of the inner view

Comment: This is the best solution, Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <View style={styles.imageCancel}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(!this.state.visible) }}>
                 <Text style={styles.textCancel} >Close</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 imageCancel: {
         height: 'auto',
         width: 'auto',
         justifyContent:'center',
         backgroundColor: '#000000',
         alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
     textCancel: {
        paddingTop:25,
        paddingRight:25,
        fontSize : 18,
        color : "#ffffff",
        height: 50,
        },
 }};
```

[image]