# Display inline-block equivalent in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I need to achieve this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ghxfpL7j/1/

In React Native but:

- You can't have a View inside a Text
- You can't set a margin or padding for a Text

I tried having the "C" inside a View and the text and then another view for the other Text with the number but I couldn't achieve the same because when the name is too long it does not work.

This is what I tried:

```
<View style={a}>
  <View style={b}><Text style={c}>C</Text></View>
  <Text style={d}>Player name</Text>
  <View style={e}>20</View>
</View>
```

and then styles:

```
a: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
}

b:{
  width: 20,
  backgroundColor: '#000'
}

c:{
  color: '#ddd
}

d:{
  flex: 1,
  text-align: 'right'
}

e:{
  text-align: 'right'
}
```

Comment: Is swearing necessary?

Comment: For anyone landing here looking to simulate `inline-block` so that the width of the container is based on the width of its text, see [React-native view auto width by text inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233789/react-native-view-auto-width-by-text-inside)

Answer (score 7):

Per your link, which could be:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>C</Text>
    </View>

    <Text>Player Name</Text>
    <Text>25</Text>
</View>
```