# React native: automatically set width of container of text to the width of the text, inside a flexBox

Tags: html, css, react-native

My question is similar to this: [React-native view auto width by text inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233789/react-native-view-auto-width-by-text-inside), but none of the answers there help. I have this:
[image]

```js
<Row style={{ justifyContent: "space-around", borderWidth: 1 }}>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>hi hi hi</Text>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "pink", flexShrink: 1 }}>
    greetings everyone! my name is nathantew
  </Text>
</Row>
```

I want the blue text to take up as much space as it needs to stay a single line, and the pink text should take up the remaining space, but only as much as it needs. then the rest of the space should be distributed evenly. However, when the pink text requires more than a single line, this happens:

[image]

I tried the solutions in the aforementioned threads, but although they successfully make the `Text` component take up less space, its parent continues to take up all the remaining space like it did before:

Wrapping in a view with `alignSelf: "flex-start"` or `alignItems: "flex-start"`:
[image]

```js
<Row style={{ justifyContent: "space-evenly", borderWidth: 1 }}>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>hi hi hi</Text>
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
      alignItems: "flex-start",
      flexShrink: 1,
    }}
  >
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }}>greetings everyone! my name is nathantew</Text>
  </View>
</Row>
```

Wrapping in another `Text` component:
[image]

```js
<Row style={{ justifyContent: "space-evenly", borderWidth: 1 }}>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}>hi hi hi</Text>
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgreen", flexShrink: 1 }}>
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }}>greetings everyone! my name is nathantew</Text>
  </Text>
</Row>
```

So, how can I make the green part have the same width as the pink part?

Comment: I don't understand why it has been set as a duplicate with that other question (it isn't a duplicate of it at all). If I understood correctly, I feel that you just need to add a flex: 1 to each child of the Row. That's not fair @Paulie_D (bro is here for the badges haha)

Comment: Then clearly you aren't explaining your requirement clearly. Show us an image of what it is you think this should look like. I'll re-open once you clarify your requirement.

Comment: However, based on your stated requirements, that the container shrinks when the text wraps... makes this a duplicate. Containers can't do that based on the way wrapping and inline flow works.

Comment: @Paulie_D it's right there in the last line... "how can I make the green part have the same width as the pink part". And also right after the first image: "I want the blue text to take up as much space as it needs to stay a single line, and the pink text should take up the remaining space, but only as much as it needs. then the rest of the space should be distributed evenly."

Comment: Which you can't do, wrapping doesn't work that way which is why the duplicate applies.

Comment: @Paulie_D you're telling me there's absolutely no way to achieve that? Not even the desired effect even if through different means?