# React native text like span

Tags: react-native

I tried to follow the solution in [Simulate display: inline in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624100/simulate-display-inline-in-react-native) but it's not work.

I would like to do the same thing just like  in HTML

First line is short so seems like no problem, but second line content is too long and it's expected to fill all the space before go to next line.

But my output is look like...
[image: output]

```
<View style={styles.contentView}>
    <Text style={styles.username}>{s_username}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.content}>{s_content}</Text>
</View>

contentView: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    flexWrap:'wrap'
},
username: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
},
content: {

},
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

React Native supports *nested* `Text` *components*, and you must use this to get your desired result. For example, you should have your second text component nested within your second, like so:

```
<View style={styles.contentView}>
    <Text>
        <Text style={styles.username}
              onPress={() => {/*SOME FUNCTION*/} >
           {s_username}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.content}>{s_content}</Text>
    </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: How about I add "TouchableOpacity" to username?

Comment: you can use the `Text` component a similar way, by using the `onPress` prop. Note you will have a seperate the `Text` components now. Ive editted my answer to show this

Comment: Is there a difference between using <Text> as a parent or <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} as a parent?

Comment: Using <Text> to wrap other <Text> components causes the child <Text> elements to be treated as inline - things like margin are ignored in these children, and positioning will be thrown off compared to wrapping the text elements in a <View> which treats its children as block components.

Answer (score 9):

you can do as nesting text as text inside will consider as span like html

```
<View style={styles.contentView}>
  <Text style={styles.content}><Text style={styles.username}>{s_username}</Text> {s_content}</Text>
</View>

contentView: {
  paddingLeft: 10,
  flex: 1,
},
username: {
  fontWeight: 'bold'
},
content: {

},
```