# How to fit an image inside the Text component?

Tags: image, react-native, text, styles, text-align

I Need to insert an image inside the text so, I do it with the most simple way:

```
const avatarurl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Golde33443.jpg'

<ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.articleContent}>
      <View style={styles.p}>
        <Text style={{backgroundColor:'pink', width: 300, height: 100 }}>
          <Image style={{width: 300, height: 50}} source={{uri: avatarurl}}/>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>

const styles = {
  articleContent: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    borderColor: 'red',
  },
 p: {
    paddingBottom: 15,
    flex: 1,
 },
 textCaption: {
  fontSize: 13,
  color: 'black',
 },
}
```

**Here is the result:**

[image]

I Don't know why the entire image is not inside the Text. So, I tried one more time with text:

```
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.articleContent}>
      <View style={styles.p}>
        <Text style={{backgroundColor:'pink', width: 300, height: 200}}>
          <Text style={styles.textCaption}>Well-known discrete probability distributions used in statistical modeling include</Text>
          <Image style={{width: 30, height: 30}} source={{uri: avatarurl}}/>
          <Text style={styles.textCaption}> the Poisson distribution, the Bernoulli distribution, the binomial distribution, </Text>
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>asdasd asd asd asd asd asdas das das d</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Ok, the image is not fitting inside the line of the text. I tried some styles like: `textAlign`, `lineHeight`. But nothing helps. Is there a way to do this? The image needs to be inside the text: 
**Like this:**

[image]

The image may not invade the space of the other line. And the words need to stay in the bottom of the line.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are after here. Do you want an image displayed in-line in the middle of a sentence? Text-image-text? Text on top of the image and if so where? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Much, much better. Try your first way (image inside the text tag) with a style of `display:inline;` or if you need to tweak the position further `display:inline-block`.

Comment: The style in react-native is made by flex-box. Display only support `Flex` or `None`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624100/simulate-display-inline-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

In order to put the image inside the text, you'll have to put the image itself in  like this;

```
<View>
 <Text> BIG TITLE </Text>

  <Text><Text>Caption text bla bla ajdjj </Text><Image style={{width: 30, height: 30}} source={{uri: avatarurl}}/> More Text bla blah blah blah blahhhhh </Text>

</View>
```

Comment: Same problem, the image is invading the other line